# Submitting Windows Phone 7.0 App to Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it still possible to submit a Windows Phone 7.0 App to the Marketplace? I know the Marketplace is only accessible by 7.5 Phones. But I have some old Codebase and want the Change to be minimal.

Comment: Is this an update to an existing app, or as a new app?

Comment: In addition, [for the moment](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/08/14/app-publishing-temporarily-on-hold.aspx) submissions are suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can.  You do not **have** to use the 7.5 features, but I would recommend you do so.  I know that when I use an app, it drives me nuts when an app doesn't use the fast app switching capability of Mango, and that doesn't require any extra code other than to switch to the newer SDK, unless you're already using tombstoning (no, not all apps need this), in which case you need to add a short if statement in app.xaml.cs to the application_activated method.

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) 
   {     
      if (!e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved)     
      {
         RestoreStateFromTombstone();
      }
   }
```

Here's a link explaining the above: http://henry-chong.com/2011/08/wp7-upgrading-your-app-from-7-0-to-mango-fas-tombstoning/

Using the 7.0 SDK is a good way to get me to delete the app, unless it is something I really need, and there is no other, and in that case, I will be watching for a replacement.